# Java Regex replace all

Tags: java, regex

My text will look like this

```
| birth_date          = {{birth date|1925|09|2|df=y}}
| birth_place         = [[Bristol]], [[England]], UK
| death_date          = {{death date and age|2000|11|16|1925|09|02|df=y}}
| death_place         = [[Eastbourne]], [[Sussex]], England, UK
| origin              = 
| instrument          = [[Piano]]
| genre               = 
| occupation          = [[Musician]]
```

I would like to get everything that is inside of [[ ]]. I tried to use replace all to replace everything that is not inside the [[ ]] and then use split by new line to get a list of text with [[ ]].

```
input = input.replaceAll("^[\\[\\[(.+)\\]\\]]", "");
```

Required output:

```
[[Bristol]]
[[England]]
[[Eastbourne]]
[[Sussex]]
[[Piano]]
[[Musician]]
```

But this is not giving the desired output. What am I missing here?. There are thousands of documents and is this the fastest way to get it? If no, do tell me the optimum way to get the desired output.

Comment: In addition to other problems, please note that `(.+)` is a "greedy" quantifier that will grab as many characters as it can between `[[` and `]]`, meaning that for `birth_place` you'll get `"Bristol]], [[England"` as one of the matches.   Adding `?` after `.+`, as in falsetru's answer, prevents this.

Answer (score 6):

You need to match it not replace

```
Matcher m=Pattern.compile("\\[\\[\\w+\\]\\]").matcher(input);
while(m.find())
{
    m.group();//result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Matcher.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29). For example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

...

String text =
    "| birth_date          = {{birth date|1925|09|2|df=y}}\n" +
    "| birth_place         = [[Bristol]], [[England]], UK\n" +
    "| death_date          = {{death date and age|2000|11|16|1925|09|02|df=y}}\n" +
    "| death_place         = [[Eastbourne]], [[Sussex]], England, UK\n" +
    "| origin              = \n" +
    "| instrument          = [[Piano]]\n" +
    "| genre               = \n" +
    "| occupation          = [[Musician]]\n";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[.+?\\]\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, using `replaceAll`:

```
 String output = input.replaceAll("(?s)(\\]\\]|^).*?(\\[\\[|$)", "$1\n$2");
```